# Python get datetime intervals of x minutes between two datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I get the list of intervals (as 2-tuples) of `x` minutes between to datetimes? It should be easy but even `pandas.date_range()` returns exacts intervals, dropping end time. For example:

In:

```
from = '2023-01-05 16:01:58'
to   = '2023-01-05 17:30:15'
x    = 30
```

Expected:

```
[
    ('2023-01-05 16:01:58', '2023-01-05 16:30:00'), 
    ('2023-01-05 16:30:00', '2023-01-05 17:00:00'), 
    ('2023-01-05 17:00:00', '2023-01-05 17:30:00'), 
    ('2023-01-05 17:30:00', '2023-01-05 17:30:15')
]
```

Comment: How 16:01:58 to 16:30:00 calculated with 30 minutes difference?

Comment: Did you check out the `inclusive` keyword of `pd.date_range`?

Comment: I did but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) and [dt.ceil](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset


from_date = pd.to_datetime("2023-01-05 16:01:58")
to_date = pd.to_datetime("2023-01-05 17:30:15")
freq = "30min"

intervals = []
start = pd.Series(from_date)
while True:
    end = (start + DateOffset(minutes=1)).dt.ceil(freq)
    if end[0] >= to_date:
        intervals.append((str(start[0]), str(pd.to_datetime(to_date))))
        break
    intervals.append((str(start[0]), str(end[0])))
    start = end
```

Then:

```py
print(intervals)
# Output
[
    ("2023-01-05 16:01:58", "2023-01-05 16:30:00"),
    ("2023-01-05 16:30:00", "2023-01-05 17:00:00"),
    ("2023-01-05 17:00:00", "2023-01-05 17:30:00"),
    ("2023-01-05 17:30:00", "2023-01-05 17:30:15"),
]
```

Comment: This does the job! Just a little fix needed. `if end[0] >= to_date:` otherwise it will add an interval with identical start and end datetime when `to_date` matches a datetime with minutes = `freq`.
For example `from='2023-01-05 16:20:00'`, `to='2023-01-05 16:30:00'` will produce `[('2023-01-05 16:20:00', '2023-01-05 16:30:00'), ('2023-01-05 16:30:00', '2023-01-05 16:30:00')]`

Comment: Right, answer updated. Cheers.